# Applescript keystroke wont work in BBEdit

Tags: applescript, bbedit

```
tell application "BBEdit"
    activate
    tell window 1
        repeat 100 times
            repeat 5 times
                key code 124
            end repeat
            --select insertion point after character 5
            keystroke return
            --keystroke key code 36
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

gives error

```
error "BBEdit got an error: Can’t get keystroke \"
\" of window 1." number -1728 from keystroke "
" of window 1
```

All I want to do is emulate moving the cursor 5 spaces and press the return key lots and lots of time.

Seemed simple enough...

Answer (score 2):

```
delay 0.2
tell application "BBEdit"
    activate
    tell window 1
        repeat 100 times
            repeat 5 times
                tell application "System Events"
                    key code 124
                end tell
            end repeat
            tell application "System Events"
                keystroke return
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```